# SQL-триггер в MSSQL для проверки вводимых данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

В БД есть две напрямую несвязанных таблицы Класс и Кабинет, необходимо реализовать триггер в СУБД MSSQL, чтобы перед добавлением или изменением записи в таблице Расписание_звонков происходила проверка, что значение ключа Вместимость в таблице Кабинет было больше, чем значение ключа Численность в таблице Класс. Если условие удовлетворяется, то запись добавляется/вносится, если не удовлетворяется, то не добавляется/вносится и выкидывается ошибка. Буду рад любой помощи.
Структуру БД прилагаю:
[image: БД]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Также настоятельно рекомендую учитывать, что показанная схема не гарантирует единственности, а потому надо агрегировать, а потом уже сравнивать.

Comment: В триггере вам доступна псевдотаблица `inserted`, имеющая такую же структуру, как из таблица на которой висит триггер, она содержит все вставленные INSERT'ом записи или новые значения изменённых UPDATE'ом строк. В триггере нужно проверить, что каждая строка таблицы удовлетворяет условию, и в противном случае выбросить исключение.